# Why am I getting errors while compiling this code and how to fix them?

Tags: c, compilation, macros, rounding

The program I'm trying to write includes a macro to round a real number to the nearest integer and a function which uses that macro to round an array of real numbers.

Here's the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 256
#define round(N) {  return (N >=0)? (int)(N+0.5) : (int)(N-0.5) ; }

void round_array(int a[])
{
   int i;
   for(i=0; i <SIZE; i++)
   {
       a[i] = round(a[i]);
   }
}                                                     

int main()
{

    return 0;
}
```

While compiling, I'm getting these errors:

```
 round.c: In function ���round_array���:
 round.c:4:18: error: expected expression before ���{��� token
 #define round(N) {  return (N >=0)? (int)(N+0.5) : (int)(N-0.5) ; }
                  ^
round.c:11:15: note: in expansion of macro ���round���
        a[i] = round(a[i]);
               ^
round.c: At top level:
```

Why am I getting these errors and how can I fix them?

Comment: Macros are not functions. Use a function instead.

Comment: isn't `round()` already a widely used function name?

Comment: @tkaus Thank you. I still don't understand why this is happening, can you explain it in a little more detial please?

Comment: @Tree Please, imagine a macro as text replacement before compile (just like search and replace with arguments). Thus, the `return` is inserted where the macro is used. You may use your compiler to expand macros only and see what finally comes out for compile. (gcc has argument `-E` for this.)

Comment: @SouravGhosh It is if you include the respective header. However, macros are resolved before compiling. Thus, it is legal to name macros like functions (but, of course, may be irritating).

Comment: Is there are reason why you can't use the `round()` function from math.h?

Answer (score 2):

Because after preprocessing, your code will look similar to that:

```
a[i] = {  return (a[i] >=0)? (int)(a[i]+0.5) : (int)(a[i]-0.5) ; }
```

If you like to stick to macro, declare it as:

```
#define round(N) ((N) >=0)? (int)((N)+0.5) : (int)((N)-0.5)
```

But this is still not really correct because of int/float mixing. That is however already a different topic.

Answer (score 1):

Like it was told to you in a comment, macros aren't functions. They are a token substitution mechanism. So you do not return from them as you would a function.

```
#define round(N) (((N) >=0)? (int)((N)+0.5) : (int)((N)-0.5))
```

The changes I made include:

1. Making it an expression. This involves replacing the curly braces with parentheses. This is so you could use the macro almost anywhere you could use a function. Had I left the curly braces it would have been a compound statement.
2. Wrapping the parameter N in parentheses as well, to make sure operator precedence doesn't come back and bite us.

Answer (score 1):

Macro-replacement is basically what it sounds like, it replaces the macro with the body of the macro, quite literally.

So when you have

```
a[i] = round(a[i]);
```

It will be replaced by

```
a[i] = {  return (a[i] >=0)? (int)(a[i]+0.5) : (int)(a[i]-0.5) ; };
```

That's not valid syntax. The right-hand side of an assignment must be an expression and not a statement.

A simple solution is to turn `round` from a macro to an actual function. An even simpler solution is to realize that `int` values (`a[i]` is an `int`) doesn't have fractions, so there's nothing to round.

If you want to use floating-point values though, the *correct* solution is to use the standard [`round`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/round) function, not to make up your own.

Comment: Thank you I still don't understand, what is the problem with this line?
     a[i] = {  return (N >=0)? (int)(N+0.5) : (int)(N-0.5) ; }; 
@Some programmer dude

Comment: @Tree Have you *ever* seen or been told that e.g. `x = { y }` is a valid ***assignment*** (remember there's a difference between initialization for variable definitions and assignments)? It's not a valid syntax. You can't have a statement on the right-hand side of an assignment operator, you must have an *expression*.

Comment: Thanks. I understand. I really meant to declare a as a floating point, mistakenly I initialized it as an int.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on writing this yourself, you should replace the icky macro with a safer, cleaner function:

```
inline int int_round (double d)
{
  return (int) ( d >= 0 ? d+0.5 : d-0.5 );
}
```

This should yield the very same machine code.

Comment: @Tree Sure, you need to study how macros work. But the thing is, a function-like macro is probably the incorrect solution here to begin with. Function-like macros are the very last resort and you need to know why they should be avoided: non-existent type safety, unreadable, hard to debug and maintain, can cause very subtle bugs, generally very dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `return` keyword, it's not a function. Get rid of it.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.8.6.4

> A `return` statement terminates execution of the **current function and returns control to
>   its caller.** [...]

which is **not** the purpose of your MACRO definition. Inclusion of `return` keyword is unwanted and invalid syntax there.

What you probably want is a syntax like

```
  (N >=0)? (int)(N+0.5) : (int)(N-0.5)
```

or, something better

```
 ( (N) >=0)? (int)((N)+0.5) : (int)((N)-0.5)
```

without the `return` and maybe the trailing `;` also.